# Laravel character string buffer too small with PLSQL

Tags: laravel, oracle, plsql

I'm having a problem with a call to a PLSQL function from Laravel. It tells me that the buffer overflowed but I don't know if the problem is in Laravel or in Oracle DB.

The problem is that the PLSQL function returns, if an exception is not found, a NUMBER type value. So I wouldn't be seeing a problem in the implementation.

This is the output error.

```
Error Code    : 6502
Error Message : ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
              : character string buffer too small
              : ORA-06512: at line 1
Position      : 0
Statement     : DECLARE l_result NUMBER;

BEGIN
    l_result := CIUD.DELETE(:id_number);
    :l_result := l_result;
END;

Bindings      : [,82]
 (SQL: DECLARE l_result NUMBER; 
  BEGIN
      l_result := CIUD.DELETE(:id_number);
      :l_result := l_result;
  END;)
```

this is how I call it from laravel:

```
    $output = null;

    $res = DB::statement("DECLARE l_result NUMBER; BEGIN l_result := CIUD.DELETE(:id_number); :l_result := l_result; END;",
        [
            'l_result' => &$output,
            'id_number' => $multimedia_id,
        ]);

    dd($output);
```

This is the PLSQL function implementation.

```
FUNCTION DELETE (p_multimedia_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
AS
    result NUMBER;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        result := UTILITIES.DELETE('TABLE_NAME', p_multimedia_id);
        RETURN result;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            RETURN -1;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RETURN 0;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: What does UTILITIES.DELETE function return?

Comment: Btw. naming a function `DELETE` in my opinion might be source of problems, since `DELETE` is a keyword.

Comment: This is odd as the exception handler in the delete function should catch the ORA-06502. Can you check if there is an anonymous PL/SQL block in the `CUID` package that might cause this error on initialisation of the package?

Comment: Can you execute the anonymous PL/SQL block directly in a database client (sqlplus, SQL Developer) and see if you get the same result?